# Application authentication config with jsf and spring-security

Tags: spring, jsf, authentication, spring-security, spring-webflow-2

I thinking about solution like this:

- different menus for users depend on role which will be included template
- proper `sec:intercept-url`'s to access only those pages which are dedicated to role, so user with one role won't be able to access pages for another role

What are You thinking about this solution?

`masterLayout` look like:

```
<h:body>
    <f:subview id="menuUser" rendered="#{sessionBean.user}">
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/menuBarUser.xhtml" />
    </f:subview>
    <f:subview id="menuAdmin" rendered="#{sessionBean.admin}">
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/menuBarAdmin.xhtml" />
    </f:subview>
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</h:body>
```

`security-context.xml:`

```
... 
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I catch up your question right, but sounds like you can use [Spring Security Facelets Tag Library](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s09.html).

Comment: Looks like much easier to do, thanks! Will see if it will work with my app